# Convert django function generic view into class-based generic view

Tags: django, django-generic-views, django-class-based-views

I've added a "user" field to all of my models.  When a user creates an object, I want to attach their ID through a foreign key

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Previously, I was using create_object and update_object.  I believe I need to switch to class-based generic views in order to most easily insert the required user into the record.  But I'm confused on how I institute some of the pre-calculations that were occuring in my previous function before create_object or update_object were called.

I have one function that handles all object editing, whether creating or updating:

```
@login_required 
def edit_item(request, modelname, submodelname=None, slug=None, id=None):
    # Get parameter "next" to determine where to send user after object is created or updated

    # Define which template to use

    # Determine whether user is converting an object to another type

    # Determine which form_class to use based on modelname and whether user is converting or not

    # Redirect user if slug and id are not both correct

    # Abort if user hit cancel instead of submit

    # If object exists (slug and id are defined):
        # Update_object with form_class, object_id, template_name, post_save_redirect, and extra_context
    # Else
        # Create_object with form_class, template_name, post_save_redirect, and extra_context
```

Within a class-based generic view, how/where/when do I perform some of these calculations (logic around defining template or form_class based on criteria)?  I'm confused because the docs seem to go straight to the definitions:

```
class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'
```

Could I just throw the logic there?

```
class ContactView(FormView):
    A = 1 + 2
    if A == 3:
        template_name = 'contact.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'contact_two.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'
```

And how would/should I alter my logic to divert into using CreateView or UpdateView vs what I've done here in using create_object or update_object in the same function depending on whether slug/id are defined?

Comment: Why convert Django function? Generic views is not so convenient. The one big minus is **inheritance** instead of composition. It's more practically to create your own class-based views or use view function. BTW generic views is deprecated in newest Django versions.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I create a class-based view that isn't based on the generic class-based views?  I know function-based create/update_object are deprecated, but I thought they were being replaced by the generic class-based views.

Comment: Excuse me for the disinformation. Any way, think enough before using class-based generic views. It's sometimes a lot of pain if you want to add a new class in an intermediate position of an inheritance chain. If one class has several children and the one child must have a feature of the new intermediate class and the other child mustn't have the feature then refactoring required. You have to handle common parts in several functions. In my practice it becomes a little inflexible structure. Please look over there: http://dpaste.com/hold/823122/

Answer (score 1):

Class-based generic views have methods that are used for the tasks you need. For example, for a form that creates an object you use `CreateView`, and to define which form is used override `get_form_class()` method.

I strongly suggest you to, instead of trying to convert your current logic exactly, take some time to learn the details of the class-based views, as many common features are already solved there in detail.